# How to calculate the Big O notation of the following expression?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I want to find the Big O notation for the following expression.

[image]

Can it be represented as [image] [where 1<=l<=alpha, beta is a vector of integers]

Correct me if I am wrong....

Comment: You want the find the complexity of this expression as a function of _which_ variable?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for multiple variable, both alpha and beta

Comment: I think the question is incomplete, whether the series `beta` follows some pattern ? like is it a GP,AP or something.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar beta is an integer, no pattern

Comment: Beta is not an integer.  It is a vector of integers.  You cannot subscript an integer.

Comment: @StephenC correct, thanks for pointing it out to me, updated the question

Comment: So does my Answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm for computing that sum would be:

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (int i = 1; i <= alpha; i++) {
     sum = sum.add(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(beta[i]));
}
```

Now the complexity of an N-bit shift or an N-bit add using `BigInteger` is `O(N)`.

Therefore, the overall complexity of computing the above will be bounded by `alpha * min(beta[i])` and `alpha * max(beta[i])`.

Furthermore, the actual complexity will also depend on the *order* of the `beta[i]` values.

If the `alpha` and `beta` values are small enough that you can use primitive integer arithmetic, then the complexity is `O(alpha)`, since both adding and shifting are `O(1)` operations.

---

On the other hand, if you want the complexity class for that function, it is going to be something like `O(alpha * 2 ^ (max(beta[i])))`.  Note that this is actually a function of a scalar and a vector, and I'm not sure that this is a mathematically sound thing to say.  (What does it mean for a vector to tend to infinity?)

Comment: shouldnt the complexity be like this: 2^(argmax beta[i])?

Comment: Yea ... I just realized that.

Comment: will alpha get multiplied at the beginning? I was not sure about it....

Comment: oh yes it should, my bad

Comment: Yea it will.  Consider the case where Beta vector consists of all 1's.